# Is the quotients of a group of triangular distributed numbers still following a triangular distribution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a group of numbers (about 10000 numbers) between 0.8 and 1.0 which follows simple triangular distribution (for example, lower limit: 0.8, upper limit: 1.0, mode: 0.9).

If I divide 2 by each number from this group, I got the quotients forming the second group of numbers which follows another distribution (i.e. lower limit: 2.0, upper limit: 2.5, mode: 20/9).

Here is my question: is the second distribution still a triangular distribution? If not, then how can I know quantitatively what kind of distribution it is?

I will appreciate very much for your kind answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We work with your numbers $0.8$ and $1$. So the base of the triangle has length $0.2$. To make the area $1$, the height of the triangle needs to be $10$.

We are dealing with a random variable $X$ whose density function we could readily find. In order to follow what is coming, you need to draw a picture of that triangle.

Now we look at the random variable $Y=\dfrac{2}{X}$, and we want a description of the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, or maybe its density function, you did not specify. We go after the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$. You can then differentiate if you need the density function. The distribution will **not** be triangular, though it it looks roughly triangular.

The effective range of $Y$ is, as you pointed out, $2$ to $2.5$. Let $F_Y(y)$ be the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, that is, $\Pr(Y\le y)$. It is clear that $F_Y(y)=1$ if $y\ge 2.5$, and $F_Y(y)=0$ for $y\le 2$. We now need to do some work to find $F_Y(y)$ for $y$ in the interesting interval, $2$ to $2.5$. We have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr\left(
\frac{2}{X} \le y\right))=\Pr\left(X\ge \frac{2}{y}\right).$$

First deal with the case $y \ge \frac{2}{0.9}$. Then $\frac{2}{y}\le 0.9$. We want the probability that $X\ge \frac{2}{y}$. This is the area of the part  of the triangle that is to the **right** of $\frac{2}{y}$.

The area of the part of the triangle that is to the **left** of $\frac{2}{y}$ is easier to find directly. This is a triangle with base $\frac{2}{y}-0.8$. The height of the triangle is $100(\frac{2}{y}-0.8)$. So the area of the triangle is $50(\frac{2}{y}-0.8)^2$, and therefore for $y \ge \frac{2}{0.9}$ (but $\le 2.5$) we have
$$F_y(y)= 1-50\left(\frac{2}{y}-0.8\right)^2.$$
Of course I don't trust my calculation. So let's check what happens at $y=\frac{2}{0.9}$, where the answer should be $0.5$. It is! The answer should be $1$ at $y=2.5$. Yup.

Now we need to deal with $y$ between $2$ and $\frac{2}{0.9}$. The probability that $Y\le y$ is the area of the part of our original triangle which is to the right of $\frac{2}{y}$. The base of this triangle is $1-\frac{2}{y}$. The height turns out to be $100$ times that, so for $2\lt y\le \frac{2}{0.9}$ we have
$$F_Y(y)=50\left(1-\frac{2}{y}\right)^2.$$

We can differentiate to find the density function $f_Y(y)$.

If you graph the resulting density, the distribution of $Y$ will probably look triangular to the casual eye. It isn't, we have the exact distribution above. But triangular is likely a good enough approximation  for your purposes. If you went say $0.15$ to $1$ instead of $0.8$ to $1$, the departure from triangularity would be significant. Here it may not be.

**Added:** Explicitly, by differentiating the expressions for the cdf above, we find that $f_Y(y)$, the density function of $Y$,  is in the interval $(2,2.5)$  given by:

$f_Y(y)=\dfrac{200}{y^3}(y-2)$ for $2\le y \le \frac{2}{0.9}$, and

$f_Y(y)=\dfrac{200}{y^3}(2-0.8y)$ for $\frac{2}{0.9} \lt y\lt 2.5$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explicit answer André. This is really helpful to me. I just wonder if you mind me ask you another question. I followed your answer and get the same answer as you did. When I plot the answer, I noticed that, to the left of the mode (in this case it is 2/0.9), the pdf is concave, and to the right of the mode, the pdf is convex. My question is, will it be always like this (left concave right convex), regardless of the values of original values of X?

Comment: @Lotus: I am not sure I understand the question. In a smallish sample, anything can happen, since the observed distribution may not be close to the theoretical distribution. With a quite large sample like yours, it is overwhelmingly likely that the geometry of the theoretical distribution will be well-mirrored by the sample.

Comment: Never mind! This is just something I suddenly want to ask. Thanks again for your kind answer!

Answer (score 0):

The mgf of the triangular distribution is $$M_{X}(t) = \frac{2(b-c)e^{at}-(b-a)e^{ct}+(c-a)e^{bt}}{(b-a)(c-a)(b-c)t^{2}}$$

where $a,b,c$ are the lower limit, upper limit, and mode respectively. Note that this is an alternate way of characterizing the probability distribution function. Replacing $a := 2/a$, $b:= 2/b$ and $c:= 2/c$ still produces a triangular distribution.

Comment: The distribution of the new random variable $\frac{2}{X}$ is not triangular, though for most practical purposes triangular is close enough.

Comment: @FastingGuy Thanks for your answer! I learned the MGF which I did not know before from your answer.